# SQL: How do I query distinct pair within an existing group by?

Tags: sql

For example, if I had a table as follows:
[cat] [paramA] [paramB]

and would like to construct a query to output
[cat] [count of distinct paramA/paramB pairs].

eg.

```
cat    paramA    paramB
001   A         B
001   A         C
001   B         B
001   A         C
002   A         A

desired output:
cat    count
001    3
002    1
```

I'm using [cat] as my group by parameter, and don't know how to make distinct work on the pair of values within this framework.

Comment: Can you concatenate paramA+paramB in a view, then count that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to select distinct on cat, paramA, and paramB. Then do your group by on that result:

```
select cat, count(*) from 
(select distinct * from data) as tmp
group by cat
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/76f57/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate paramA and paramB for calculating DISTINCT count

```
SELECT cat, COUNT(DISTINCT paramA + paramB) AS [count]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY cat
```

[**Example on SQLServer2008**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1dac1/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may really need to specify the DBMS you are using, because some of them, like e.g. [PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/752fb/1), would allow you to do something as simple as this:

```
SELECT cat, COUNT(DISTINCT (paramA, paramB))
FROM atable
GROUP BY cat
;
```